# How can make PG_DUMP work without asking password?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, password

I have set pgpassword in `.bashrc`:

```
vim .bashrc 
export PGPASSWORD=pass_for_postgresql
```

It is no need to type password for command  `psql -U postgres`.
When i dump a table from db1 into db2 with :

```
pg_dump -U postgres -t table db1 | psql -U postgres -W db2
```

The command will ask me to type password.
I have googled an article to dicuss this
http://www.londatiga.net/it/database-it/how-to-use-postgresql-pgdump-in-crontab-without-password/

Create a ~/.pgpass file in user’s home directory with the following format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
Ex: localhost:5432:mydatabase:lorenz:lorensxyz
```

There are many databases here,how can write the .pgpass file then?

```
localhost:5432:db1,db2,db3,db4:postgres:pass
```

How can make PG_DUMP work for all databases without asking password?

Comment: Yes, making it prompt for a password is what -W does.  If you don't want that, don't use -W.  This is no different between psql and pg_dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.pgpass`. The entry could look like

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:pass
```

to work with any database in the cluster. Make sure that the file has no permissions for anybody but the owner.